# iis virtual directory application using non admin custom account in app pool

Tags: iis, web-server, .net, windows-server-2019

web server Microsoft Windows Server 2019 DataCenter version 10.0.17763

there is a physical folder on the d drive folder1 --app1 --app2 --app3 --web.config

folder 1 is set up as a web application in iis. (mywebsite) its app pool is v4.0 classic Application pool Identity

there is a requirement to put another folder / application under this website. mywebsite.folder2 there is also a requirement that this application run under an app pool with a non admin service account (myservice account)

I created folder2 containing this .net web application

I created a virtual Directory on mywebsite pointing to folder 2. I created an app pool for this website running as the non admin service account (the application never runs and never gives an error) If I switch the app pool to run as an admin account everything works fine.

Any thoughts what permissions / rights I need to give the non admin service account? or where I can find an actual error (I searched through the event logs and found nothing)

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure the account running the application pool for mywebsite.folder2 has at least Read access to it's home directory (the c:..\ folder it points to)
2. view/edit/enable the IIS logging directory as per https://theitbros.com/configure-iis-log-location-on-windows-server-2016/
   a) Open IIS Manager (on the server hosting the website)
   b) Single-click the name of the server in the left pane
   c) Double-click 'Logging' in the right pane